# Why these errors are shown

Tags: php, web

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/a0/public_html/index.php on line 17
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a0/public_html/index.php on line 17

Why these errors are shown?

```
<?php

define('IS_DEMO', (gethostname() === 'youtubify' ? 1 : 0));
define('VERSION', 1.5);

require __DIR__.'/application/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/application/bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
$response = $kernel->handle{
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() // line 17
};
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
?>
```

Comment: what is your local PHP-version?

Comment: You have to double the backslashes in `$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');` because backslash is an escape character in Javascript strings.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann PHP version 5.2.*

Comment: @trincot the error is in another line

Comment: I know, and it is not an answer to your problem, but an issue you need to fix anyway.

Comment: Another issue (not on that line): you need to add brackets around the object you pass to `$kernel->handle`, like `$kernel->handle({ ... });`

Answer (score 2):

You are using namespaces, which were introduced in PHP 5.3.0.
PHP 5.2 does not support them.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

I do not know if there is a way to backport namespace-support to PHP 5.2.* and I guess if there is, it is several times harder and more experimental than updating your PHP-installation.